# Microsoft Graph Maximum number for List OneDrive Items?

Tags: c#, list, limit, microsoft-graph-api, items

i tried to list all items within a Onedrive folder.
In this folder there are exactly 333 files of same type.

The request via Microsoft Graph delivers only 200 items for this folder.

Same number of files i got back when i did a search for files (or file extension)! Exactly 200.

**Is there a limit for the items/children?
Is it possible to retrieve all items/children within a folder?**

Answer (score 2):

The OneDrive API returns a default page size of 200 items (mentioned [here on the List Children page](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/list.htm#response)). You should have a property on the JSON object named @odata.nextLink, which is a URL your app can use to request the next page of content (the remaining 133 items in your example).

You can also use the [?top=500 query string parameter](https://dev.onedrive.com/odata/optional-query-parameters.htm#optional-odata-query-parameters) to control the page size to something that works better for you, or to be able to test this behavior by setting the page size to something smaller (like 20 items).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening for me right now with Sharepoint list as I have 369 items in the list and it continues to return 200.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_odata_nextLink_files(accessToken, graph_data, folders_data, files_data):
        if '@odata.nextLink' in graph_data:
            graph_data = requests.get(graph_data['@odata.nextLink'], headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}, ).json()
            drive_data = graph_data['value']
            for item in drive_data:
                if 'folder' in item:
                    folders_data.append(item)
                elif 'file' in item:
                    item.update({'size':formatBytes(item.get('size',0),1)})
                    files_data.append(item)
            get_odata_nextLink_files(accessToken, graph_data, folders_data, files_data)
        return graph_data, folders_data, files_data
        

graph_data = requests.get(user_endpoint, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}, ).json()
graph_data, folders_data, files_data = get_odata_nextLink_files(accessToken, graph_data, folders_data, files_data)
```

Comment: This works for me (in python) to fetch all the files and folders present inside a folder (also root). I hope this can be useful for you too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).