# Microsoft Graph - Children of OneDrive folder not listing - too many items?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Graph Explorer, if I list all the children of my root, using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/children`, I get a listing of all my folders and files under the root. If I use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{target folder}:/children`, I get the following:

```
{
    "@odata.context": 
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('{drive-id}')/root/children",
    "value": []
}
```

This is a very large subdirectory with many items. When I access other folders under the root, it displays the children just fine. I've tried adding `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{target folder}:/children?top=5`, I've tried filtering, I've tried looking at a subdirectory three levels deep. The three levels deep query returns a `Item not found` error, otherwise, I'm getting no other clues.

1. Is there a folder size limit for use within the API?
2. Is there a way around it? [Microsoft Graph Maximum number for List OneDrive Items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772614/microsoft-graph-maximum-number-for-list-onedrive-items) seems to just mention top as a possibility.

Comment: Have you tried using the folder's id instead (`/drives/{driveid}/items/{folderid}/children`)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did try that but forgot to mention above.

Comment: This behavior isn't expected. I'll need to look at diagnostic logs on the server. Can you please try this request again, and give me the value of the 'request-id' header that comes back from the graph response as well as the time in UTC?

Comment: Just tried it. UTC time is `Thursday, October 25, 2018 around 23:55`

`request-id: f9cc2ba0-f7df-43eb-a4c8-b8c458edb175`

Comment: Thank you! We are investigating.

Comment: @caelon thanks for your patience! Our team was able to find the logs and they indicate that the folder was indeed empty. So now we need to confirm that we're talking about the same folder. It's probably better if we take this to email. Can you reach out to me at dspektor @ microsoft . com? Thank you!