# How to get more than 200 items from OneDrive folder using php?

Tags: php, curl, onedrive

I use OneDrive for my photos/videos backup.  I learned how to get a list of all mp4 files from OneDrive so I can view them on one page.  My problem is that some folders contain over 1000 files but with only a few mp4 files, and that the method I found so far only retrieve the first 200 files.

Is there a way to increase the number of items returned from OneDrive using the above method?

Or is there a way to only get a list of the files matching a criteria (filename contains .mp4)?

Is there another way to do this?

Here is my script...

```
$folder = 'https://1drv.ms/u/s!xxxx?e=5xprOy'; // obtained from OneDrive

// get correct url for json
$url = 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/u!'.base64_encode($folder).'/root?expand=children';

//  initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();

// return response | if false print response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

// execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);

// close
curl_close($ch);

// get result into array
$arrayFolder = json_decode($result, true);

// loop files
foreach ($arrayFolders['children'] as $file) {
    if (str_contains($file['name'],'mp4')) {
         // get download link             
         $videos[$i]->link = $file['@content.downloadUrl'];
         $i++;
    }
 }

 ...
```

Comment: It's seem the same problem there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772614/microsoft-graph-maximum-number-for-list-onedrive-items

Comment: What does your response with the 200 file look like? In your response is there a URL?

Comment: @Misunderstood there is an url called children@odata.nextLink which I understand holds the next 200 files and so on.  However because there is only let's say 100 mp4 files in the 1000 files in that folder, I would prefer to fetch them in one go (increasing the number of items i.e top=1000 - but that does not seem to be compatible with my curl) or add a filter to only return the mp4 files.

Comment: @svgta Thank you for that but I have no idea where to add the top parameter in my script. I tried inside at the end of $folder and $url but then there is an error.